# Maven : is it possible to merge two ears?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, build, ear

I have two ears and I whant to merge them to make just one ear.
Is it possible to do that with maven ?
If yes, please explain.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) goal of the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to place the contents of the two ears in the same folder:

> - dependency:copy takes a list of artifacts defined in the plugin configuration section and copies them to a specified location, renaming them or stripping the version if desired. This goal can resolve the artifacts from remote repositories if they don't exist in either the local repository or the reactor.
> - dependency:unpack like copy but unpacks.

And pack them up again with the ear plugin, which should take care of creating all the necessary descriptors, I suppose.